# Confusion with Bitwise NOT on char c++

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm currently reading "C++ Primer" and I'm on a section about bitwise operators.

I get it but I dont get this exercise..

> What is the value of ~'q' << 6 on a machine with 32-bit ints and 8 bit chars, that uses Latin-1 character set in which 'q' has the bit pattern 01110001?

The Answer given was:

> The final value in decimal is -7296.

How did they get there?

Basically, I need an explanation of what the whole `~'q' << 6` means and how they got that negative number.

Comment: The exercise describes   the target system fairly well, but to answer it correctly, it also needs to specify the representation that is used for negative numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When 'q' = 0b01110001 then in decimal format q=113.
Not q(~q) = ~113 = -114 (0b1111111110001110).
When we left shift -114 by 6 we get -7296 (0b1110001110000000).

Comment: Use ``0b`` prefix for binary numbers

Comment: we do ~q which is ~113 which is -114(why -114 and not -113?) @Asesh

Comment: The reason it's -114 is because [this is how two's complement works](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html).

Comment: @iMarioOfficial, We use Two's complement mathematical operation on binary numbers in computing as a method of signed number representation. Wikipedia page is quite informative https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement. Using one's complement as mentioned by you (-113 instead of -114) will give rise to problem where we have 0 and -0.

Comment: `q` is an 8-bit `char`. It is **not** a 32-bit signed integer. Its value is **promoted** to `int` when the `~` operator is applied to it.